# Partial proof for correlation coefficient formula?

Tags: statistics, correlation

I've been working to prove the formula for the correlation coefficient, since asking my last question yesterday ([Meaning of denominator in correlation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019939/meaning-of-denominator-in-correlation)). If this post in any way violates any guidelines, then please let me know.

So far, I've proved that the constant is 1 when $(X_i-\bar X)=(Y_i-\bar Y)$, and -1 when $-(X_i-\bar X)=(Y_i-\bar Y)$

What I want to do now, is to prove that for any other value, the denominator is larger than the numerator, making the constant smaller than 1, but larger than -1

That is to say that $\sum(X_i-\bar X)(Y_i-\bar Y) < \sqrt{\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2\sum(Y_i -\bar Y)^2}$

If we develop the numerator, we get:

$\sum(X_i-\bar X)(Y_i-\bar Y)$

$\sum X_iY_i-2n\bar X\bar Y + n\bar X\bar Y)$

$\sum X_iY_i-n\bar X\bar Y$

If we develop the denominator, we get:

$\sqrt{\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2\sum(Y_i -\bar Y)^2}$

$\sqrt{(\sum X_i^2-n\bar X)(\sum Y_i^2 -n\bar Y)}$

$\sqrt{(\sum X_i^2\sum Y_i^2 -n\bar Y\sum X_i^2 -n\bar X \sum Y_i^2  + n^2\bar X \bar Y}$

....Which is as far as I get. Put together:

$\sum X_iY_i-n\bar X\bar Y$ < $\sqrt{(\sum X_i^2\sum Y_i^2 -n\bar Y\sum X_i^2 -n\bar X \sum Y_i^2  + n^2\bar X \bar Y}$

Can we develop this in any meaningful way, and prove that the denominator is greater than the numerator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an illustration of how to use Cauchy Scwarz inequality in this case:

You want to show: $\sum(X_i-\bar X)(Y_i-\bar Y) \leq\sqrt{\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2\sum(Y_i -\bar Y)^2}$

CS inequality gives us:
$$\sum a_ib_i \leq\sqrt{\sum a_i^2\sum b_i^2},$$ here equality occurs if $a_i=c_1+c_2b_i$ $\forall i$,  where $c_1,c_2\in R$.
Take $a_i=(X_i-\bar X)$ and $b_i=(Y_i-\bar Y)$, then you are done.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up Cauchy Scwarz inequality, the one one wikipedia looked....frightening ^^ I'll just take for granted that someone, somewhere has proved it to be reasonable! :)

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz inequality is a very common inequality used in mathematics. There are various way to prove it. Below link has good collection of proofs.http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Frgmia.org%2Fpapers%2Fv12e%2FCauchy-Schwarzinequality.pdf&ei=EgVmVJM8kJS4BImRgZgB&usg=AFQjCNGGiKGgZJ1AIsDoLH6PHNguj7czqg&bvm=bv.79142246,d.c2E

Comment: Worked through the inductive proof (the easiest one). This seems to work if 2abcd < aabb + ccdd. Does this lead to another inequality? Pardons for being tedious ^^

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [Cauchy Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).